# How to get the current vertical scroll bar position with Avalon TextEdtior

Tags: avalonedit

External Resourse:   http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42490/Using-AvalonEdit-WPF-Text-Editor

I am using the editor for showing a log file and would like it to always scroll to the button when a new line are added, but only if it was at the bottom already.

I have found a ScrollToEnd() but this means it always scroll and i need someway to get the current scrolling position? Anyone who have found it or know if it do not exist?

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
TextView textView = textEditor.TextArea.TextView;
bool isAtEnd = textView.VerticalOffset + textView.ActualHeight + 1 >= textView.DocumentHeight;
```

The code adds 1px to avoid problems with floating-point inaccuracies.